# Matrix calculation not working... very odd output Java

Tags: java, math, matrix

This is what I want to do when A is a **square** matrix.

P - is power.
A & B are square matrices.

User will be asked to enter size of matrix A, and elements of matrix A and to what power they want to raise the matrix to.
Once they input what power, and what elements my program is supposed to calculate this:
(Assuming P = 5)

A^5 + A^4 + A^3 + A^2 + A

I have written a method that adds matrices a method that multiplies them, and a method that raises them to the power and they all work correctly.

The problem I am having is the final step which I showed above *A^5 + A^4 + A^ 3...*

This is where the problem gets even weirder, my program works when the elements in the matrix are all the same... such that a

```
2 2 2
2 2 2
2 2 2
```

matrix will give me the CORRECT output, BUT

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

matrix will give me the WRONG output and I have no idea why.

This is the method in which the problem is occuring

```
public static void addPowers(int [][] a, int[][] b, int p) {
    while( p != 1){
        b = addMatrices(powerMatrix(a,p), b)  ;
        addPowers(a,b,p-1) ;
        return ;
    }
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < b.length; j++) 
                System.out.print(b[i][j] + "\t") ;
                System.out.println();
        }

}
```

Just in case you ask, reason I have the recursive under a while loop is so it won't print over and over and over again.

Thanks for your time! :)

Edit: More clarifying information.
addMatrices is a method that adds matrices with an two int[][] arguments.
powerMatrix is a method that finds the power of a matrix with (int[][], int) arguments.

**EDIT** Methods being called...

```
public static int[][] multiplyMatrices(int matrixA[][], int matrixB[][]) {
    int temp[][] = new int[matrixA.length][matrixB.length];
    int matrix[][] = new int[matrixA.length][matrixB.length]; 
    int sum = 0 ;

    for (int i = 0; i < matrixA.length; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < matrixB.length; j++) 
        {
            for (int l = 0; l < matrixA.length; l++)
            {
                sum += matrixA[i][l] * matrixB[l][j] ;
            }
            temp[i][j] = sum ;
            sum = 0 ;
        }
        }
    matrix = temp;
    return matrix ;
}


public static int[][] addMatrices(int matrixA[][], int matrixB[][]) {
    int temp[][] = new int[matrixA.length][matrixB.length]; 
    int sum = 0 ;

    for (int i = 0; i < matrixA.length; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < matrixB.length; j++) {
            {
                sum = matrixA[i][j] + matrixB[i][j] ;
            }
            temp[i][j] = sum ;
        }
    }
    return temp ;
}


public static int[][] powerMatrix (int[][] a, int p) {
    int[][] result = a;
    for (int n = 1; n < p; n++)
        result = multiplyMatrices(result, a);
    return result;
}
```

Comment: "Just in case you ask, reason I have the recursive under a while loop is so it won't print over and over and over again" - that's silly. Just separate the computation and the printing into their own methods.

Comment: You should give your `powerMatrix()` method for more information. In `addPowers()` method you should change `while` to `if` although it will not cause problem because of the `return` statement.

Comment: I found it easier to just do it like that @user2357112 is all.

Comment: Where does matrix B come from?

Comment: @Pants: At least use an `if` instead of a `while`. You're not actually looping.

Comment: Ok check the edit. It's just many methods, I didn't wanna put down so many but I guess the more the better. @locoyou

Comment: Lol, why do you guys not like the while loop, its literally the same thing, same result. @user2357112 but fine I'll change it

Comment: They may produce the same result, but the `if` more clearly communicates intent. It is very important that code be easy to understand.

Comment: `addMatrices` is seriously messed up. Matrix addition is elementwise; the inner loop shouldn't be there. Also, separate `temp` and `matrix` matrices are redundant.

Comment: yeah .... lol I was being lazy and just copied the multiplyMatrices over and touched it up a bit... it still works though. @user2357112 its not any of those trust me, I already debugged those methods like 50 times. I still cleaned it up, but it still doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: @Pants: Test addMatrices with some simple inputs. You'll find that it gives the wrong answer.

Comment: yeah it was, thx. But im still getting the wrong output... check the edit, i fixed it. @user2357112

Comment: @Pants: It's still wrong. You're treating matrix addition as if it were matrix multiplication with a plus sign. It's not; it's defined completely differently.

Comment: yeah i realized. im doing it now.

Comment: I got it. it was that :), and I was indicating the wrong point of element when querying user too so when I compared it to my calculator it got the same numbers but came out in different places. Like when I asked for element (3,2) I was actually asking for (2,3) (row 3 position 2) . Thanks man! @user2357112

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `addMatrices` method, you should remove the third loop.

Like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < matrixA.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < matrixA[i].length; j++) {
        temp[i][j] = matrixA[i][j] + matrixB[i][j] ;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Pants OK, then I think at least your `addMatrices` method make a mistake when add two matrix, you need two loop instead of three

Comment: same thing I said to @user2357112... it looked funny but it worked, I was being lazy and copied and pasted from my multiplyMatrices method. I cleaned it up but problem still persists.

Comment: @Pants If your matrix is all same number, it is no matter which element you add. Why not copy my code and test it? your newest edit still has a problem

Comment: yes it was that! i really have no idea how I messed that up. I guess thats what you get for trying to things the short lazy way.